# Is there any way to do Javascript networking (AJAX / Comet / WebSockets) without "Serverside" code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, networking, websocket, client-side

I ask because I currently host my website on Github Pages, which as far as I know doesn't have any ability to run any code server-side. Obviously I need to have some sort of server for the networking to actually happen, but I was hoping I would be able to designate one of the client machines as host, as many games do.

EDIT: Yes, I meant server-side.

Comment: ?? I don't understand the "... without client side code" part; is that supposed to be "without **server** side code"?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The whole concept of AJAX is when a piece of code on the client makes a request to the server.  You can use iframes but I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Um, your title !== Your post